# This is my code for keycode inputs, but nothing is happening - plain Javascript and not jquery

Tags: javascript, keycode

This is my javascript code:

```
var coinNumber;
coinNumber = 1
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
    if(event.keyCode == 65) {
        coinNumber = coinNumber + 1
    }
    else if(event.keyCode == 83) {
        coinNumber = coinNumber + 2
    }
});
document.write("Coins: " + coinNumber)
```

there are no error messages, but nothing happens when I press the "a" or "b" keys

Answer (score 2):

```js
document.write("Coins: " + coinNumber)
```

should be inside the

```js
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
    if(event.keyCode == 65) {
        coinNumber = coinNumber + 1
    }
    else if(event.keyCode == 83) {
        coinNumber = coinNumber + 2
    }

    document.write("Coins: " + coinNumber) // <- 
});
```

because otherwise the `document.write` won't get called when the event is fired.

Though using `document.write` here is a bad idea because it will overwrite the whole document, meaning it will also clear all the event listeners.

Better would be to just log to the console (`console.log("Coins: " + coinNumber)`) or if you need to set the body text use

```js
document.body.innerText = "Coins: " + coinNumber
```

```js
var coinNumber;

coinNumber = 1

document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode == 65) {
    coinNumber = coinNumber + 1
  } else if (event.keyCode == 83) {
    coinNumber = coinNumber + 2
  }

  console.log(event)

  document.body.innerText = "Coins: " + coinNumber
});
```

```html
<html><body>Hello</body></html>
```